# Atlas280 IDE alternatives

Tags: ide, rad, cappuccino, objective-j

Are there any alternatives to 280Atlas (280atlas.com) (free/commercial)?
Which of those are mature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nib2cib](http://wiki.github.com/280north/cappuccino/nib2cib), which is pretty much the same idea, but it uses interface builder (part of xcode) to create the interface, then translate the nib (or xib) to a cib.

Answer (score 2):

Interface Builder + `nib2cib` is not in itself a workaround, though the use of an “external tool” may make it seem so.  Actually by using a master set of .nib files, one may leverage IB’s great power (which Atlas is catching up with) and interchangeably use them between Cocoa apps and Cappuccino apps.  However, nib2cib looks for keys and values inside .nib files and there are a few classes that it still does not recognize.  You can provide new class definition files so `nib2cib` works with everything you use.

Interface Builder comes with XCode with many other tools included in Apple’s free Cocoa SDK.